# Convert MM/DD/YYYY date to different format. DATE_FORMAT not working

Tags: mysql

I have the table below and im trying to change date format to something mysql can easily use. Seems anytime i query this date its not easy.

```
CREATE TABLE test.tbl_master_copy (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  theme varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  upload_date date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Here is what the data looks like

```
1   Voice Search    KitKat Experience   11/27/2013
```

I have tried adding a new date column with DATE_FORMAT and it produces nothing

```
UPDATE tbl_master_copy
SET upload_date2 = DATE_FORMAT(upload_date, '%m-%d-%Y')
```

I even tried changing the column to char and varchar and using this and still updates nothing

```
UPDATE tbl_master_copy
SET upload_date2 = STR_TO_DATE(upload_date, '%m-%d-%Y')
```

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE()` is the correct course of action, but the second arg is the _original_ format of the string, not the target format, so you need `STR_TO_DATE(upload_date, '%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: Question before i try that. The original format of the column is date. so STR_TO_DATE will not work. So i change to VARCHAR then do this? is there a way to do it without doing that?

Comment: I changed to VARCHAR and the date changes automatically to 2013-11-27. so i did this STR_TO_DATE(upload_date, '%Y-%m-%d') and it changed back to the original format of 11/27/2013. Im fine with this format if its the standard and easy to manipulate. is that true?

Comment: No, the standard format of a proper date column is YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: If `upload_date2` is a proper DATE type, you should be able to populate it with `UPDATE tbl_master_copy SET upload_date2 = STR_TO_DATE(upload_date, '%Y-%m-%d')`  After that, you'll be able to use any of the date functions to manipulate `upload_date2` without having to convert it from a string.